# Firefox - transparent png taking CSS background attribute's while firefox is refreshing cached images

Tags: html, css, firefox

Working on an image heavy website, discovered a strange bug(?) in Firefox. Any CSS background properties are rendered onto transparent png's. It occurs after the initial render, during the cache refresh. This appears as a flicker if you're using broadband but becomes extremely noticeable as you scale down bandwidth.

General progression of the issue seems to be:

1. Page and images rendered from cache
2. Firefox removes the cached images.
3. Firefox begins to reload images but displays a box with the CSS properties of the background.

I've recreated a (hideously colorful) [example](http://infinovate.net/transparency/), but you may need to use fiddler, or another program with bandwidth throttling/emulation to see anything more than a flicker. Obviously, you'll also have to load once and then refresh to experience the error. And again, it's only in Firefox.

I have tried a plethora of various suggestions, none worked. Just need **a** fix, hacks will work as long as they don't effect other browsers.

EDIT: Here's a [video](http://tinyurl.com/7sbgzke) so you can see it in action.

Comment: I'm running Firefox on a less than speedy download and I do not see any "box with the CSS properties of the background" unless you mean the black background before the `body` image loads. That just means the overlays have not loaded and neither has the image on the body, so it is displaying the default black background. That is expected (I would assume in any browser with a slow load speed).

Comment: P.S. It takes about 5 sec. for me to load your example page, so I am having plenty of time to see anything.

Comment: @ScottS - The initial(uncached) load appears with the functionality that you're describing, which is default web behavior. The reload however is definitely following the above steps. This is, thus far, confirmed on Firefox 10.0.2 and Firefox 11.0.

Here's a video: http://tinyurl.com/7sbgzke,
you can see the "black box" effect. On sites with images for the background, the image will show. Interestingly enough, it will be correctly positioned, in what appears as a knockout (not shown in demo).

Comment: First: clarify your images as background statement; your example uses an image as a background, and it is obviously not showing the green when the black boxes are showing, so what do you mean by "the image will show?"

Comment: Second: I'm running 10.0.2 and if I hit refresh, then nothing obvious occurs (pulls from cache), but if shift+refresh, then the whole page reloads, and the background disappears (into black) until that image reloads, while the other images are loading also. In my case, usually the foreground loads _before_ the green background gets loaded. Maybe in your case the background reloads rapidly, and then the video driver redraws the area for the foreground and "erases" the image it is going to draw over. Perhaps it is a difference in video drivers, since we are not experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @ScottS - I've expanded the demo to further highlight the issue. I've also posted a [screenshot of the issue](http://www.projectgruene.com/exhibit_a.png). As you can see more clearly here, when the images start to refresh (they should just load from cache... but they still reload...), they appear as solid boxes taking on the background-color of the back-most element. 
It seems that updating to FF11 has caused the background-image part of the to stop appearing in the box, however the background-color still does...

updated demo [here](http://infinovate.net/transparency2/)

Comment: I'm not sure how this differs from the video you posted (except it has yellow as the background color). I see the squares in your demos, but not in my experience on my Firefox browser. That is why I am beginning to wonder if it is _purely_ a browser issue, or a combination of browser and video card, because if it is not purely browser, but also something with hardware, then you are not likely going to be able to correct it (but also, not everyone will experience it... like me).

Comment: The differences between the two are rather minor, I just wanted to highlight the knockout effect. I'm beginning to think that I may need to log this in Bugzilla. Realistically, the best I can do is hope that Mozilla can work this out so no one else has to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot recreate the issue on my Firefox (10.0.2) on my computer (Win 7) with my particular hardware (which may or may not be a part of this problem), I offer the following ***as a guess*** at a solution, though one I would have assumed you tried already.

Target your `img` tags (preferably with some css more specific than below) that you have the issue with and try setting one of the following:

Either:

```
img {background-color: transparent;}
```

Or:

```
img {background-color: transparent !important;}
```

**Update: Another Possible Workaround**

Have javascript make the relevant `img` tags invisible to start and also bind an event to them so that when they load, they become visible again (JQuery example):

```
$('img').css('visibility', 'hidden'); /*not using "display" keeps layout*/
$('img').bind('load', function() {
    $('img').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

I cannot test the above, so no guarantee it will work, but is another idea.

Comment: This was one of the first things that was tried. It makes sense, but it doesn't work. =/

Comment: @BG_Insight--added a possible javascript work around, but I cannot test it.